# Express "female strength" in Latin

Tags: classical-latin

I am trying to find a name for a company related to a feminist movement. I put in "female strength" and it came back *Vi Femina*. Is this correct? I checked a different site and put in that *Vi Femina* and it came back with zero results. Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Femina is a noun, [feminina](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DF%3Aentry+group%3D10%3Aentry%3Dfemininus) is the related adjective. Does that fit your purpose?

Comment: " in genere Amazonarum mulierum, ubi *fortitudo* et *robur* *feminarum* prefertur fortitudini virorum, ..."

Thomas Cantimpratensis

Comment: Do you want to say "feminine strength" or "strength of women"?  They seem slightly different in tone to me and may have some bearing on vocab choice (and definitely on the grammar).

Answer (score 6):

What about *feminarum potestas*? The word *potestas*, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potestas), is core in Roman Law, and reflects "a manifestation of socially recognized power". Might be fitting for the company's spirit.

The above phrase assumes plural object, and translates as "the power of women". An alternative is *feminae potestas*, meaning "the power of woman", but I think the plural might be better.

Joonas also suggests *potestas feminina*, meaning "feminine power". A good option for sure.

Comment: How about the option *potestas feminina*? The plural genitive is good, but the adjective is a worthwhile option.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Added to the answer. Will share the credit with you.